# Encrypt files before sending them to Cloud

Tags: encryption, git, privacy, version-control, cloud

Recently I switched to GIT along and picked bitbucket to host my code.

Now with all the snowden scandal, I decided to review my choices.

I *really* don't want to host my data on my own server, I'd rather keep using bitbucket for that.

I have nothing but good words about bitbucket themselves, but I just want to make sure my private data (source code) stay that way.

I know many folks used TruCrypt with DropBox, I wonder if this is feasible with bitbucket (ie. **force git to transparently and automatically encrypt source code & files before it's sent to bitbucket**), if so anyone could share how to do that? I googled a lot but couldn't figure out the proper way to do that.

Comment: I'm going to say this is not possible.  Git relies on the content of the files in your repository being the same in order to do what it does (everything is based on hashes of the files).  If you encrypt the file, you change them, and break the system.  If you don't trust BitBucket, don't host your code there.

Comment: @heavyd: Obviously if TheDude encrypts all his files, he will need to refresh them all in BitBucket – once. As long as he uses the same encryption tool (algorithm) with the same key, why would it be a problem after the initial hurdle? An unchanged file, encrypted with the same key, is still unchanged.

Comment: @Scott, if BitBucket were just plain cloud storage like Dropbox then there would be no problem, but BitBucket is a source code repository which is built on top of SCM systems like Git and Mercurial.  Being based on Git is what makes this difficult.  Git won't work well with the encrypted data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution could be to use  git's `smudge` and `clean` [filters](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). 
This solution has some serious downsides though, which we will come to later.

You'll need to write two scripts that act as filters, i.e. read from standard input and write to standard output. From the documentation:

> A filter driver consists of a clean command and a smudge command, either of which can be left unspecified. Upon checkout, when the smudge command is specified, the command is fed the blob object from its standard input, and its standard output is used to update the worktree file. Similarly, the clean command is used to convert the contents of worktree file upon checkin.

For example when using openssl we can write the files `fooenc.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
openssl enc -bf -nopad -pass pass:1KjeHD8d6YUI80bIIEAQ9iYr@njqLw3T
```

and `foodec.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
openssl enc -bf -nopad -d -pass pass:1KjeHD8d6YUI80bIIEAQ9iYr@njqLw3T
```

Note that these scripts should be kept *outside* of the repository and that they should be kept *secret* since they contain the key! Otherwise they're convenient because they don't ask for a passphrase everytime they are called.

A somewhat more secure alternative might be to use GPG.

In the `.git/config` file in your repository you should specify these filters;

```
[filter "crypt"]
    clean = fooenc.sh
    smudge = foodec.sh
```

This is *not* a typo! See the documentation excerpt above. This setup encrypts data on checkin, and decrypts on checkout.

Then in the repository's `.git/info/attributes` file, you specify to use this filter for all files;

```
* filter=crypt
```

As long as the filtering scripts are available, the working directory will contain readable files. But the git objects will be encrypted.

Note that this precludes actually *using* the files on any machine that doesn't have the necessary scripts. So bitbucket would only work as a storage.

Now for the downside; This solution also makes tools like `git diff` and everything that depends on that *useless*, since git's objects are now encrypted blobs.

**Edit:** 
There are utuilities like [git-crypt](https://www.agwa.name/projects/git-crypt/) or [git-encrypt](https://github.com/shadowhand/git-encrypt) to help you with encrypting your repo's contents.

And there is a solution to the diff problem; using a special filter for diffs; using [textconv](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv) with an additional script to decrypt the blobs before they are diff-ed.

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/polonskiy/7e5d308ca6412765927a96bd74601a5e) seems to explore the idea further (using textconv as suggested).