# How to encrypt data in bitbucket without losing git diff tools?

Tags: linux, bash, encryption, git

Based on this question:[encrypt files before sending them to cloud](https://superuser.com/questions/676497/encrypt-files-before-sending-them-to-cloud).

considering openssl:
For example when using openssl we can write the files `fooenc.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh 
openssl enc -bf -nopad -pass pass:1KjeHD8d6YUI80bIIEAQ9iYr@njqLw3T
```

and `foodec.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
openssl enc -bf -nopad -d -pass pass:1KjeHD8d6YUI80bIIEAQ9iYr@njqLw3T
```

In the `.git/config` file in your repository you should specify these filters;

```
[filter "crypt"]
    clean = fooenc.sh
    smudge = foodec.sh
```

i tried this approach and it occurred me:

```
error: cannot run fooenc.sh: No such file or directory
error: cannot fork to run external filter ourenc.sh
error: external filter fooenc.sh failed
```

**Where am i suppose to put this *.sh?**

Even that if i try to put

```
 [filter "crypt"]
        clean = openssl enc -bf -nopad -pass pass:1KjeHD8d6YUI80bIIEAQ9iYr@njqLw3T
        smudge = openssl enc -bf -nopad -d -pass pass:1KjeHD8d6YUI80bIIEAQ9iYr@njqLw3T
```

even thought it occurred me:

```
bad decrypt
3074115260:error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length:evp_enc.c:414:
error: external filter openssl enc -bf -nopad -pass pass:1KjeHD8d6YUI80bIIEAQ9iYr@njqLw3T failed 1
error: external filter openssl enc -bf -nopad -pass pass:1KjeHD8d6YUI80bIIEAQ9iYr@njqLw3T failed
```

Another aproaches were take in place like [git-remote-encrypt](https://github.com/bluss/git-remote-gcrypt) or another using [GnuPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig/9733277#9733277):

In `.git/info/attributes` use:

```
myPrivateInfosFile filter=gpg diff=gpg
```

In your repo `.git/config` file:

```
[filter "gpg"]
smudge = gpg -d -q --batch --no-tty
clean = gpg -ea -q --batch --no-tty -r C920A124
[diff "gpg"]
textconv = decrypt
```

At last, using [git-remote-encrypt](https://github.com/bluss/git-remote-gcrypt) approach it occured me:

```
gcrypt: Remote ID is :id:k/a9sdsd332e3442wdaJ
Counting objects: 102, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (71/71), done.
Total 102 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
gcrypt: Encrypting to: --throw-keyids --default-recipient-self
gcrypt: Requesting manifest signature
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: [stdin]: sign+encrypt failed: secret key not available
error: failed to push some refs to 'gcrypt::rsync:https://example@bitbucket.org/ourstuffteam/our.git'
```

None of this was a successful approach.

** According to this or others new approaches. How can i encrypt data into git more properly into bitbucket?**

Comment: Who cares about where to put it? Just use absolute paths. Also, because these commands probably use pipes, use `exec` when putting these commands in an external script.

Comment: yes, you are right. first i used absolute paths outside of repo, but needs permissions. `~/ourenc.sh: 1: ~/ourenc.sh: /home/mypc/ourenc.sh: Permission denied` even if i write the command line directly it occurs me  `Bad Decrypt`

Comment: If it says “Permission denied” the file wasn’t executable (+x). Can’t help you with the rest, but you might want to try without `-nopad`.

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the noise about being a new user, and make clear where your problem is different from the question you link to. If it's not different then it simply *is* a duplicate and will be closed as such.

Comment: @DanielB thans for your suggestion. I don't  know why, removing `-nopad` it works it will encrypt. The unique problem now is how to put .sh files outside the repo since that i need permissions to execute inside `.git/config`. @Arjan this is not a duplicate question since that it gives 3 approaches to the same problem, for that reason  edited this question like you have suggested taking this issue as a question based on another and not duplicate. to solve encrypt issues on git.

Answer (score 1):

I used your attempt for some try-and-error and found a solution for your `git-remote-gcrypt` error. See my question [Setting up an encrypted git repository](https://superuser.com/questions/1162907/setting-up-an-encrypted-git-repository).

You simply need to run

```
gpg --gen-key
```

which starts a dialogue to create a `gpg` key that can later be used for pushing to bitbucket. Compare the `gpg man`ual

```
How to manage your keys

       This section explains the main commands for key management

       --gen-key
              Generate a new key pair using the current  default  parameters.   This  is  the
              standard command to create a new key.

              There  is also a feature which allows you to create keys in batch mode. See the
              the manual section ``Unattended key generation'' on how to use this.
```

<del>Though, I don't know about further usage yet.</del>

### edit

I just tried to clone that repository onto another machine. Obviously one needs the `gpg`-key (and secret-key, whose name is implying that this is a bad idea) for that, so I decided to simply copy mine to the other machine. Sadly it does not work this way, such that we probably need to add other users.