# Setting up an encrypted git-repository

Tags: encryption, git, version-control

### Situation

Hi, I would like to save data with git, encrypted (on some platform like [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or [github](https://github.com/)). Therefore the question:

## Question

I am looking for different hassle-free ways on:
How to set up an **encrypted repository on bitbucket**(/github)?
Now, I am new to git, thus an instruction with **all necessary steps** or step by step would be much appreciated!

### "Research"

**git-crypt**
I found [git-crypt](https://www.agwa.name/projects/git-crypt/), but on the site it is mentioned that it's intended for single file encryption. If one wanted to encrypt the whole repository they forward to [git-remote-gcrypt](https://spwhitton.name/tech/code/git-remote-gcrypt/).

**git-remote-gcrypt**
In their [README.rst](https://github.com/spwhitton/git-remote-gcrypt/blob/master/README.rst) they put it as simple as

> **Quickstart**

```
git remote add cryptremote gcrypt::rsync://example.com:repo
git push cryptremote master
> gcrypt: Setting up new repository
> gcrypt: Remote ID is :id:7VigUnLVYVtZx8oir34R
> [ more lines .. ]
> To gcrypt::[...]
> * [new branch]      master -> master
```

or under

> **Examples**

```
# notice that the target git repo must already exist and its
# `next` branch will be overwritten!
git remote add gitcrypt gcrypt::git@example.com:repo#next
git push gitcrypt master
```

### Tries

I prefer full repository encryption, hence I tried `git-remote-gcrypt` with variations of the *Quickstart* and *Example*.
So far I tried pushing an existing repository by following their instructions. Which yields this: (note: I have purposely changed the username to `user`)

-> with `ssh` as in the provided example

```
[...]/git_test$ git remote add origin gcrypt::git@bitbucket.org:user/test.git
[...]/git_test$ git push -u origin --allgcrypt: Development version -- Repository format MAY CHANGE
gcrypt: Repository not found: git@bitbucket.org:user/test.git
gcrypt: Setting up new repository
gcrypt: Remote ID is :id: ...
Zähle Objekte: 10, Fertig.
Komprimiere Objekte: 100% (6/6), Fertig.
Total 10 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
gcrypt: Encrypting to: --throw-keyids --default-recipient-self
gcrypt: Requesting manifest signature
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: Fehler beim Versenden einiger Referenzen nach 'gcrypt::git@bitbucket.org:user/test.git'
```

or with `https` (which worked)

```
[...]/git_test$ git remote add gitcrypt gcrypt::https://user@bitbucket.org/user/test.git
[...]/git_test$ git push -u gitcrypt --allgcrypt: Development version -- Repository format MAY CHANGE
Password for 'https://user@bitbucket.org': 
gcrypt: Repository not found: https://user@bitbucket.org/user/test.git
gcrypt: Setting up new repository
Password for 'https://user@bitbucket.org': 
gcrypt: Remote ID is :id: ...
Zähle Objekte: 10, Fertig.
Komprimiere Objekte: 100% (6/6), Fertig.
Total 10 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
gcrypt: Encrypting to: --throw-keyids --default-recipient-self
gcrypt: Requesting manifest signature
Password for 'https://user@bitbucket.org': 
To gcrypt::https://user@bitbucket.org/user/test.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master konfiguriert zum Folgen von Remote-Branch master von gitcrypt.
```

Nevertheless, I don't understand **how to add users or** even just **pull my backup** onto another machine (since my gpg key was generated locally) !?
Feel free to just answer on usage of `git-remote-gcrypt`.

Comment: These might be related:  - http://superuser.com/questions/676497/encrypt-files-before-sending-them-to-cloud The [filter][3]s link provided led me to believe that this is tricky usage of a git functionality that changes code(/content) upon push/pull. And the en-/de-cryption is done by the provided scripts. If that is the case, then I'd rather prefer a way that is easier to setup without the hassle of those scripts - programs like git-remote-gcrypt. Moreover this would reveal the contents of the repository, right?

Comment: - http://superuser.com/questions/900656/how-to-encrypt-data-in-bitbucket-without-losing-git-diff-tools Similar question specifically with bitbucket that has no answer.

Comment: Have a look at https://gist.github.com/shadowhand/873637

Comment: @Nifle seems to be the filter method as in my first comment, right? Does this encrypt the whole repo or just file-contents?

Comment: As I added there http://superuser.com/a/1162909/626063 : simply copying the key (and secret-key) does not suffice to clone the repo to another machine.

Comment: Have you looked at [git-remote-gcrypt](http://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/fully_encrypted_git_repositories_with_gcrypt/) or [Keybase](https://keybase.io/blog/encrypted-git-for-everyone) ?

Comment: @harrymc, I have had a look at both just now. Sadly I am too busy to test these solutions, but Keybase looks like a easy all in one tool (probably hassle free, if a whole team uses it; though, I did not see compatibility with git only) and the steps at the git annex page seem to show a few steps that I had not done; so definitively a good hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 26):

A free and partially open-source tool is
[Keybase](https://keybase.io/blog/encrypted-git-for-everyone) :

> Git supports remote helpers. And we've made an open source one.
>
> Keybase's remote helper performs all the crypto while letting git do its thing. This might sound impressive, but Keybase has not reimplemented git from scratch. We provide a remote helper, powered by the excellent go-git project, which we've begun contributing to.
>
> We bring to the table: (1) crypto, (2) team + multi-device key management, (3) a safer concept of identity.
>
> It is end-to-end encrypted. It's hosted, like, say, GitHub, but only you (and teammates) can decrypt any of it. To Keybase, all is but a garbled mess. To you, it's a regular checkout with no extra steps.
>
> Even your repository names and branch names are encrypted, and thus unreadable by Keybase staff or infiltrators.

Teamwork is supported via
[Keybase Teams](https://keybase.io/blog/introducing-keybase-teams) :

> A Keybase team is a named group of people, with flexible membership. Let's say you work on a project called Treehouse. You could register treehouse on Keybase. This team name is universal; there can be only one Keybase team with a given name.
>
> Teams get chats and channels. The chat looks a bit like Slack or Discord:
>
> But Keybase teamwork is end-to-end encrypted, which means you don't have to worry about server hacks.

[image: Keybase]

Comment: Nice tool there! However, it seems to be a closed eco-system. I could not find any hints showing how to work with non-Keybase-users. Is this possible? I guess forcing a whole team to use this tool or being dependent on it outweighs the benefits still.

Comment: This is open-source. Would a tool that you developed be any more open?

Comment: I was referring to the usage; and am unsure how the *git remote helpers* actually work. Could one use a key (which is not pgp, but something new, right ?) and this helper but without the gui?

Comment: I cannot answer these questions - I haven't gone that deeply into it.

Comment: can 3rd party tools work with it?

Comment: Keybase *client* is open source (for the moment), but not the server.  They just sold themselves to Zoom, and there is utter silence on the fate of the project.  Zoom has had a poor history with regard to privacy.

Comment: Keybase provides encrypted storage, available at /keybase/....  While I haven't used the git repo, I suspect it is just saved in that directory, so you could use other tools.

Comment: Watch out: "On May 7, 2020, Keybase announced it had been acquired by Zoom[12], as part of Zoom's "plan to further strengthen the security of our video communications platform". Source: https://blog.zoom.us/zoom-acquires-keybase-and-announces-goal-of-developing-the-most-broadly-used-enterprise-end-to-end-encryption-offering/

Comment: This doesn't work with any non-Keybase git hosting. It doesn't work with Github or Gitlab or such. Whenever Zoom decides to shutdown Keybase hosting, the one and only remote will be lost.

Comment: NOT open-source! As mentioned by @Diagon only the client has been open-sourced but NOT the server. The github ticket for open-sourcing the server is likely to stay open forever: https://github.com/keybase/client/issues/24105

Answer (score 6):

Step by step instructions, using git-remote-gcrypt and Bitbucket:

### Prerequisites

- GnuPG (`brew install gpg` on macOS)
- [git-remote-gcrypt](https://github.com/spwhitton/git-remote-gcrypt) (`brew install git-remote-gcrypt` on macOS)

### Overview

This guide will walk you through the process of creating and using a git repo called “gcrypt-sample” with Bitbucket, taking advantage of git-remote-crypt with a dedicated PGP keypair to provide end-to-end encryption.

**Every push will be a force push!**

### Steps

#### Setting Up

1. Set up your local and remote repositories:

   - Set up local repository with `git init gcrypt-sample`
   - On bitbucket.org, create a repository `gcrpyt-sample`
2. Set up your ssh key if you haven’t already: `ssh-keygen`
3. Add a gcrypt remote: 
   `git remote add cryptremote gcrypt::git@bitbucket.org:user/gcrypt-sample.git`
4. Generate your GPG keypair. Recommend [this guide](https://alexcabal.com/creating-the-perfect-gpg-keypair); for this sample, simply running `gpg --gen-key` will work.
5. Configure gcrypt to accept the gpg key you just created:

   1. `git config remote.cryptremote.gcrypt-participants <GPG key fingerprint>`
   2. `git config remote.cryptremote.gcrypt-signingkey <GPG key fingerprint>`
6. Edit your git repo:

   1. `echo 'Hello, world!' > hello.txt`
   2. `git add hello.txt`
   3. `git commit`
7. `git push -u cryptremote master`

   - If you have multiple PGP keypairs, you’ll have to cycle through until you get the one you want—this is because you pull before pushing, every time; see the note below.

#### A note about pulling from the repo

Everytime you pull down (including when you push), you will have to cycle through your PGP keys until you get to the correct one. The reason for this is that the default for git-remote-gcrypt is to use a privacy guard which redacts the identity of the signing key. Consequently, when pulling from the repository, you have to check all of your available keys to see which one is the signing key. The signing key used can be published (and therefore anonymity revoked) by setting the `remote.cryptremote.gcrypt-publish-participants` property (to anything).

If you set an explicit and singular PGP key for the repo, doing that should be fine. However, doing so does have implications for shared repos (different commits can be tied undeniably to different users).

### What’s Encrypted?

To my naked eye, pretty much everything.

#### What IS encrypted

- Filenames (including paths)
- File contents
- Branches (I don’t know if the *first* branch pushed is logged under master, but all subsequent ones were)
- Commit history: There is a single commit (“Initial commit”) and a single date (although dates of your pushes may be tracked by your remote separately, of course—BitBucket’s “Last updated” shows the accurate time. Of course, Bitbucket’s probably not paying attention to the commits themselves—it’s probably assuming you’re doing that.)

#### What is NOT encrypted

- Repository name (though that’s obvious enough); just use a codename
- The number or size of files (they are not distributed in any way); not sure what the implications are for different branches

Comment: git-remote-gcrypt seems like a bad choice because unless I misunderstood it, it can force push everything (merged into a single remote commit) each time. This makes it completely unscalable for pushes. Also, there is no support available, no maintained binary, and no place for users to discuss various issues.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, fail with an error and there's no support available.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had an issue syncing two different machines via an encrypted repository on GitHub with the help of `git-remote-gcrypt`. So I hope the following will answer the questions on **how to add users** or **even just pull my backup**.

#### Other Sources

These are the sources I used:

- https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-remote-gcrypt/git-remote-gcrypt.1.en.html seem to be the official manpages.
- https://caolan.uk/notes/2017-04-27_encrypted_git_repositories.cm
- https://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/fully_encrypted_git_repositories_with_gcrypt/
- https://www.alwaysrightinstitute.com/gcrypt/
- these might also be helpful for comparison against other tools: http://ptspts.blogspot.com/2017/10/comparison-of-encrypted-git-remote.html

### Prerequisities

I assume that you have setup separate gpg keys on your two computers (`key1` on machine 1, `key2` on machine 2). Additionally you should create a preferabily private
repository on Bitbucket, GitLab or GitHub. I assume a GitHub repository here.

### Installation

You should be able to install `git-remote-gcrypt` easily via

```
sudo apt install git-remote-gcrypt
```

or the equivalent statement in your distro. Otherwise the above sources have more information on the installation.

### Global configs on both machines

#### Compatibility with gpg-agent

In order to use the `gpg-agent` to decrypt the repository run the following command on both machines

```
git config --global --add gcrypt.gpg-args "--use-agent"
```

#### Optional: publish participants

see this note: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-remote-gcrypt/git-remote-gcrypt.1.en.html#gcrypt.publish
To use the option run on both machines

```
git config --global --add gcrypt.publish-participants true
```

#### Exchange gpg keys

see also here: https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x56.html

1. On machine 1 run: `gpg --output key1.pgp --armor --export key1`
2. and on machine 2: `gpg --output key2.pgp --armor --export key2`
3. Copy the file `key1.gpg` to machine 2 and vice versa with `key2.gpg`.
4. Then run on machine 1: `gpg --import key2.gpg`
5. and on machine 2: `gpg --import key1.gpg`
6. After importing the keys you have to validate them as explained in the link above.

Of course you could also use only one key. Then you need to copy the secret key from one machine to the other.

### Setup

#### Initial push on machine 1

1. `cd` into the folder that you want to sync or backup
2. `git init`
3. Run `git remote add origin gcrypt::git@github.com:<USER>/<MY_REPO>.git`
4. Add the keys that are used to encrypt the repository: `git config remote.origin.gcrypt-participants "key1 key2"`
5. In case that `key1` is not your default signing key on machine 1, add it as signing key for this repository with `git config remote.origin.gcrypt-signingkey "key1"`.
6. Add erverything `git add .`
7. And commit: `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
8. Optional: `git branch -M main`
9. And push the repository: `git push -u origin main`

#### Clone on machine 2

1. `git clone gcrypt::git@github.com:<USER>/<MY_REPO>.git`

   1. In case you get prompted to type in the password for your gpg key, cancel until you see that you`re typing the password for the correct key.
   2. Ignore the `warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.`
2. Then `cd` into the newly created folder.
3. `git pull origin main`
4. And switch to correct branch: `git checkout main`
5. Add the participants list on this machine: `git config remote.origin.gcrypt-participants "key1 key2"`.
6. In case that `key2` is not your default signing key on machine 2, add it as signing key for the repository on machine 2 with `git config remote.origin.gcrypt-signingkey "key2"`.

#### Test syncing between both machines

1. Add and commit a change on machine 2.
2. `git push`
3. Run `git pull` on the first machine. See the newly added content.
4. Do the same three steps on machine 1 and pull on machine 2.

### Troubleshooting

#### gcrypt: Failed to decrypt manifest!

Make sure that the key that is used to sign the manifest file is in the keys listed in `remote.origin.gcrypt-participants`. Use the config variables `user.signingkey` or `remote.origin.gcrypt-signingkey` to specify the key that is used for signing.

If you want to use a separate key (`key3`) to sign your git commits from the keys in the `remote.origin.gcrypt-participants` list (`key1` and `key2`) you need to use the following config:

```
git config user.signingkey "key3"
git config remote.origin.gcrypt-participants "key1 key2"
git config remote.origin.gcrypt-signingkey "key*"  # Use the correct key depending on your machine!
```

Therefore the git config variables have the following functions in connection with git and gcrypt

- To sign your commits, git uses `user.signkey`
- To sign the manifest file, gcrypt uses `remote.origin.gcrypt-signingkey`. If that is not set, gcrypt bounces back to `user.signingkey`. Whichever key is used to sign the manifest, this key needs to be part of the `remote.origin.gcrypt-participants` list.
- gcrypt encrypts your repository, so that it can be decrypted with the keys listed in `remote.origin.gcrypt-participants`.

#### Connection reset by peer after `git repack`

As mentioned in the manpages `git-remote-gcrypt` sometimes repacks the repository (https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-remote-gcrypt/git-remote-gcrypt.1.en.html#KNOWN_ISSUES). In my case this lead to a `Connection reset by peer` error over ssh. Currently, I have to ways to solve that problem:

1. Delete your GitHub repo and recreate it newly. Then re-initiate the connection from your local repo to the newly created remote repo.
2. As this is a very bad solution I tried to also add a https remote:

##### Use https remote

I created a (classical) personal access token for GitHub and added a separate git remote for https on both machines:

```
git remote add https gcrypt::https://<USER>@github.com/<USER>/<MY_REPO>.git
# very important to not destroy your repo!!!!
git config remote.https.gcrypt-participants "key1 key2"
git push https # you get several prompts for your https password/token
# pull with the following command
git pull https
```

I forced a repack with this https remote and the `Connection reset by peer` error did not occur. However, I do not know what will happen when the repack is initiated by gcrypt itself.

#### restart gpg-agent

In many cases it does make sense to restart gpg-agent with `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` or restart your terminal. This will solve the `not found` issues as mentioned here: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-remote-gcrypt/git-remote-gcrypt.1.en.html#KNOWN_ISSUES

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually worked for me. The only thing I had to figure out was the format of the keys in your description. For others: One can use `gpg --list-public-keys` to get the fingerprint key values in the right format. They are supposed to be inserted without any spaces. For example, key1 could mean something like A123B456C...2123CD34.

Answer (score 1):

For people following the answer by [Niklas Netter](https://superuser.com/a/1750771/1710607) of using [git-remote-gcrypt](https://github.com/spwhitton/git-remote-gcrypt) installed with

```
brew install git-remote-gcrypt
```

Its normal for the final git push to say "repository not found"
this is mentioned in the github readme under ["known issues"](https://github.com/spwhitton/git-remote-gcrypt#known-issues)
However it still failed for me at the last bit with the error of

```
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: [stdin]: sign+encrypt failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device"
```

**What commands did I execute:**

```
git remote add gitcrypt gcrypt::git@github.com:YourUserName/your-git-repo.git#main
git push gitcrypt main
```

**Result of those commands:**

```
gcrypt: Repository not found: git@github.com:YourUserName/your-git-repo.git
gcrypt: Setting up new repository
gcrypt: Remote ID is :id:123/someidehere
gcrypt: Due to a longstanding bug, this push implicitly has --force.
gcrypt: Consider explicitly passing --force, and setting
gcrypt: gcrypt's require-explicit-force-push git config key.
Enumerating objects: 6, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
gcrypt: Encrypting to: --throw-keyids --default-recipient-self
gcrypt: Requesting manifest signature
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: [stdin]: sign+encrypt failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:YourUserName/your-git-repo.git#main'
```

However i was able to fix this by following the advise of this [other stackoverflow ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57591830) by simply adding this to your bash/zsh profile

**Final fix:**

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in a decoupled way by using an actively developed **user-space encrypted filesystem** tool such as [gocryptfs](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs) or [cryptomator](https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator). The file paths are also encrypted.

### gocryptfs usage

Personally I prefer gocryptfs over cryptomator because the former is a single binary and can also more easily be automated. That's even though cryptomator looks to be a more mature project.

[**gec**](https://github.com/impredicative/gec) is a bash utility which attempts to make it more convenient to use an encrypted gocryptfs filesystem in a git repo. At a minimum, note the `-sharedstorage` option which it uses with gocryptfs.

### Cryptomator usage

1. Create an encrypted vault in say `~/cryptomator/encrypted/myvault1`. Optionally delete the useless file `IMPORTANT.rtf` from this directory.
2. Run `git init` in the above directory containing the encrypted vault. Add one or more git remote URLs.
3. Decrypt the vault into say `~/cryptomator/decrypted/myvault1`. Add or change one or more files in the unlocked vault.
4. Commit and push all changes in the git repo.